# Как эмулировать зажатие кнопки Ctrl?

Tags: c#, .net

Сабж.
Делаю кликер, мне надо нажимать Ctrl+LMB.
Клик мышкой делаю так:

```cs
public void leftClick(Point p)
{
    Cursor.Position = p;
    Thread.Sleep(350);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Winforms?......

Comment: есть метод Win API `keybd_event`, работает похожим образом как с мышью

Comment: Эмм консольное приложение. А нажатия происходят в другом окне.

Comment: ну тогда точно `keybd_event`.

Comment: Приводите больше информации. Например, что такое `mouse_event`? Следовало указать, что это функция WinAPI. Для какой платформы код? Ведь на C# можно писать и для Линукса, и для Андроида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0000; // New definition
private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag

public const int VK_LCONTROL = 0xA2;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    // This simulates a left mouse click
    public static void Ctrl_MouseLeft(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        // Key Ctrl + Mouse Left
        keybd_event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Ctrl_MouseLeft(x,y); // x, y Position mouse
    }
```

Comment: Половина экрана мобильного - это пустое место в коде, отступы. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы отформатировали его.